# Custom view like calculator LCD

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, calculator, android-custom-view

I want to design a custom view that looks like this:

[image]

I searched for a solution, and what I got was to extend an `EditText` and customize it. I looked into the notepad editor example from Android, which did not help me much since I want to split the `EditText` into at least 4 parts.

The upper one is where `M` and `DEG` is written, the right part is where the x10^012 is written, the left part contains the current operation, and the last part is the biggest one where the digits are on.

However, I want you to guide me to the right direction to do it properly and tell me what pre-built view I should use as a base class to design this custom view. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to extend the `RelativeLayout` class and in the constructor inflate an xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <TextView /> // M     DEG(or 2 `TextView`)
   <ImageButton /> //ImageView for the operation
   <TextView /> //the digits
   <TextView /> //the extra digits 10^12
</RelativeLayout>
```

Custom `RelativeLayout` class:

```
public class CustomView1 extends RelativeLayout {

    public CustomView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.lcd_layout, this, true);

        TextView part1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.the_id);
        //other stuff
    }

    public CustomView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);        
    }

    public CustomView1(Context context) {
        this(context, null);        
    }

}
```

Comment: How to add the xml to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just design that in your layout? Stack some `LinearLayouts` on top of each other?

*edit* example of border question:

put this in your res/drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/c1"
                android:endColor="@color/c2"
                android:angle="270" />
             <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/stroke_color" />
        </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Comment: But how can I add a border that can contain the 4 parts together as one view?

Comment: create a shape in xml with the a stroke and set the main layout's background as that.

Comment: `No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/stroke_color').`

Comment: you must define the color `stroke_color` in a file called `colors.xml` in the `res/values` folder. Like so `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="stroke_color">#444</color>
</resources>`